# MySQL - How to set a default value as TIMESTAMP on varchar column

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-5.7

I need to add current timestamp as a default value in a varchar column in **MySQL 5.7**

Here is table query I am trying

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
creation_time VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, col1 VARCHAR(100)
)
```

Comment: Column `creation_time`, as the name implies as well as its current_timestamp feature , is a datetime type. Why do you have to use varchar for a datetime type ?

Comment: @blabla_bingo actually it's existing system, now they want to add a default value to unused column. I cannot add a new column for datetime

Comment: 'TIMESTAMP and DATETIME columns can be automatically initialized and updated to the current date and time (that is, the current timestamp).' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html - so not possible directly for varchar - consider a trigger..or do it in your front end

Comment: You can change the data type for the column. And I would suggest doing it. A varchar can be used  to store a datetime string, but it doesn't check the validity of values to conform datetime format like a datetime type does.

Comment: @blabla_bingo they just want to know when record is inserted, can you suggest me link aur query to do this

Comment: @P.Salmon can you help me writing that trigger.

Comment: @Mahmood Sanjrani Check the answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing the existing time has a varchar type like below:

```
create table foo (creation_time varchar(30));
```

If it's possible to change the date type, we can use:

```
alter table foo change column creation_time creation_time datetime default current_timestamp;
```

Note: The `alter table` background process includes creating a new table, then populating it based on data from the original table, and finally destroying the original table. So it should be done at an off-business time.

However, if the data type cannot be changed. Then we will have to use a trigger to do the timestamp initialization job.

```
delimiter //
create trigger timestamp_init before insert on foo for each row
begin
set new.creation_time=current_timestamp();
end//

delimiter ;
```

Now the `insert` trigger will automatically set the value for your varchar column to be the current datetime every time a new row is inserted.

```
insert foo (creation_time) values(default);
```